# How to call a Word macro with parameters

Tags: delphi, parameters, ms-word

I want to run a macro (Sub) of a Word document from Delphi.

My macro in Word is

```
Sub Macro1()  
  'Do Something
End Sub
```

and in Delphi

```
Word := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');  
Word.visible := true;  
Word.Documents.Open('c:\_3\Doc\2.docm', true, false);  
word.Run('Macro1');
```

and works well
But when I want to enhance the macro and add parameters as

```
Sub Macro1( param1 as string, param2 as string)  
 'Do Something  
End Sub
```

and calling as

```
word.Run('Macro1 "Book", "Pool"');
```

I get error as
**"Unable to run the specified macro"**
How can I call a macro (Sub) with parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must pass the macro parameters values just as normal parameters.

```
word.Run('Macro1', 'Book', 'Pool');
```

for more info read the [`Application.Run Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb209121%28v=office.12%29.aspx) MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 1):

macro code :

```
Sub TestParams(param1 As String)
   MsgBox "Param1 := enter code here" & param1
End Sub
```

It was a nightmare for me too becuase as soon as you create the macro with parameters it does not display in list of macros.

I eventually got it working by doing the following
delphi code :

```
procedure TUtils.RunMacro;
var Test : olevariant;
begin
  Test := 'Hello Word';
  WordApplication.Run('TestParams',Test);
end;
```